# Bot works with emulator but not in botframework portal

Tags: botframework

I built a simple bot which works perfectly well with emulator but doesn't work in portal when I try to test it with "Test connection to your bot". In emulator I tried with the the app id and app secret obtained from botframework and it worked fine. One thing I noticed is that the request I received from the emulator had a authorization header but the request from the portal didn't have the header.

Comment: After publishing the bot, you receive an `AppId` and an `AppSecret`. Update them in your `WebConfig` and republish the Azure WebApp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, make sure that you're using an https endpoint if you have the authorization header installed.  We only pass the auth along if you're using https to protect your app secret.

Comment: Turns out this is what exactly is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got an SSL certificate? Remember that you need to use an https endpoint.

Comment: This isn't an answer